# adhoc install fail with Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an app that will not install via iTunes 10.6.3 using adhoc, if I build it with Xcode 4.5 DP4. It works fine if I build it with Xcode 4.4.1.

All seems good with provisioning files and settings, I've re-checked everything. Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Xcode 4.5 is still in Beta. That's probably why.

Answer (score 2):

If you are absolutely sure that your provisioning profiles are valid and everything is in order with them, you should double check the "Valid Architectures" of your target's build settings and be sure you have removed armv6.

Xcode 4.5 dropped support for armv6 ([Xcode 4.5 Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html), Change ID 12282156). If you are including it, your ipa's will 
fail to install and present the " failed to install" message.